# Mockito mocking objects from inside local method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

In my class, dependencies are injected by Spring. During testing, I am using mocks. I am getting null pointer exception when I call `sys.getId("abc12345")` in the following code. I am wondering how to write a unit test that gets 100% coverage.

**Class under test**:

```
public class SystemUT implements SUTIface{

    @Inject 
    private AccountLookupDAO dao;

    @Inject 
    private OrchService service;

    public Response perform(Request req){
        String sellerId = getId(request.getSeller().getNum());

        String buyerId = null;

        if(req.getBuyerId){
            buyerId = getId(request.getBuyer().getNum())
        }

            service.execute(Request,sellerId,buyerId)

    }

    String getId(String num){
        PrefAcct prefAcctObj = dao.lookupPrefId(num,Consants.StrArr);
        PrefSysOfRecObj sorObj= prefAcctObj.getSysOfRecord();
        return sorObj.getId();
    }

}
```

**Unit test**:

```
public Class SystemUTTest{

    @Mock
    SystemUT sys;

    @Mock
    AccountLookupDAO daoMock;

    @Mock
    OrchService serviceMock;

    @Mock
    PrefAcct prefAcctObj;

    @Mock
    PrefSysOfRecObj sorObj;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        Whitebox.setInternalState(sys, daoMock, serviceMock);
    }

    @Test
    public test getId(){

        when(dao.lookupPrefId(any(String.class), any(String[].class))).thenReturn(prefAcctObj);
        when(prefAcctObj.getSysOfRecord()).thenReturn(sorObj);
        when(sorObj.getId()).thenReturn("185");

         assertEquals("185",sys.getId("abc12345"));

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish overall. your getID() test just seems to be checking that mocking works? You shouldn't be @Mocking your sys object, just initialise it as normal sys = new SystemUT() in your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your `SystemUT` class doesn't have its dependencies injected. You *could* have Spring do this by using their JUnitRunner, but it's not really a unit test then, since you'd be letting Spring dictate which dependencies get injected. Really, you want to control them, and one way to do that is to transform your class to expose its dependencies via a constructor:

```
public class SystemUT implements SUTIface{

    private final AccountLookupDAO dao;
    private final OrchService service;

    @Inject 
    public SystemUT(AccountLookupDAO dao, OrchService service) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

This will function identically to your current approach since Spring is able to inject dependencies using a constructor annotated with `@Inject`. Now, when you instantiate your `SystemUT` class for test, pass mocked objects for its dependencies:

```
@Mock
AccountLookupDAO daoMock;

@Mock
OrchService serviceMock;

private SystemUT sys;

@Before
public void setup(){
    sys = new SystemUT(daoMock, serviceMock);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(sys, daoMock, serviceMock);
}
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but I still get null pointer exception at line   PrefSysOfRecObj sorObj= prefAcctObj.getSysOfRecord(); thanks for looking into issue.

Comment: @shyamsrd - That's because there's something in that method (which you didn't post in your question) that isn't set up correctly for the test. Post the method and the stack trace and I can update my answer.